# SQL Server case sensitive database names

Tags: sql-server, case-sensitive

In MS SQL Sever, it is possible to have case sensitive database names. So in other words is there a way to create 2 databases on the same instance 'create database db1' and 'create database DB1'?

If yes, how to enable this? (I tried doing it myself, and it did not allow me to create the 2nd time, but I am not sure if I missed any setting)

Note: I have seen existing questions on this on SO but they seem to refer to the objects in the database and I am referring to the database name itself.

(The reason for the question is not to setup the databases this way but to know if such scenario can happen so as that I can include in my testing)

Comment: Check this out http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2913/sql-server-case-sensitive-collations-and-dmvs/

Comment: Not knowing 100% so cannot give it as answer, but I doubt you can do that. I've not seen it mention, plus it would cause problems with many things within sql server (physical database files, collations in system databases etc) which would need to be handled very carefully. It wouldn't be a scenario I'd worry about in a test situation

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen - not sure what you're getting at re: physical database files. By *convention* the names of the files are similar to the name of the database, but that is merely a convention.

Comment: @NoDisplayName: Thanks for the link. To quote from the page: "When inside a database with a case-sensitive collation, every object functions under the same rules" ... what I wanted to know about the database name itself. Does it become case sensitive or not

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that's why I said it needed to be handled carefully

Comment: I have always understood that SQL Server is case insensitive except if you happened to be using SSIS or SSRS.

Comment: If you use a case sensitive collation it's case sensitive. If you use a case sensitive collation for the master database, your db names will probably be case sensitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *may* be able to accomplish this by setting the server collation at install to case-sensitive, or changing it by [recreating the `master` database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179254.aspx) using a case-sensitive collation.  Since the master database is the database of user-level metadata, it stands to reason that if anything would enforce case-sensitive server object names, the master database would.

I don't know how rigid it is offhand, however.  I have a 2k8R2 server with server collation set to `Latin1_General_CS_AS`, and I have to spell database names correctly in `use` statements or when calling from linked servers.  However, none of the databases attached to that server have case-insensitive collation.  It may be that if your current DB is case-insensitive that you can use case insensitive names.  I don't know.

I've also never tried creating a DB on that server with the same name as an existing DB except with different case.  I don't know if it would allow it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create the databases in the same instance by adjusting the collation property as "CS" of the required database. [Reference](https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-check-case-sensitivity-sql-server.cfm)

MSQL Server is, by default, case insensitive; however, it is possible to create a case-sensitive SQL Server database and even to make specific table columns case sensitive. The way to determine if a database or database object is to check its "COLLATION" property and look for "CI" or "CS" in the result.

CI = Case Insensitive
CS = Case Sensitive